# Problems connecting to Samba public share from Windows 10

Tags: linux, samba, windows-10, raspbian

I have a Windows 10 machine (latest update as of 2016-10-10) which absolutely refuses to access a public Samba share on a Linux (Raspbian - Debian derivate) server, without pre-entering credentials in Windows.

#### Windows 10 client

IP address: 10.0.0.184

Not in a domain.

#### Raspbian (Debian) Samba server:

IP address: 10.0.0.2

Not in a domain.

#### smb.conf:

```
[global]

workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = %h server
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

security = share

passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes

passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user

[public]
  path = /home/public
  available = yes
  read only = no
  browsable = yes
  public = yes
  writable = yes
  guest ok = yes
```

IT should be just about 100% simple and straight-forward, right?

The scenario:

From the Windows 10 machine, I try to access the Samba server:

```
\\10.0.0.2
```

I get the following error message:

```
\\10.0.0.2 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

A specified login session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

Pretty bogus, and completely ridiculous.

The Samba log says:

```
[2016/10/14 19:10:55.209107,  0] smbd/service.c:995(make_connection_snum)
Can't become connected user!
```

So, since I've had lots of bad experiences (more or less only) with Windows file sharing in the past, I open the Credential Manager in Windows 10. There, I insert the following new entry under Windows Credentials:

Internet or network address: 10.0.0.2

User name: pi

Password: [the correct password]

Now, when I try to access the Samba server with \10.0.0.2, an explorer window opens with the "public" folder visible, as per the `smb.conf` file specification.

And when I try to open the (public) share, I'm able to open it, save and delete files, etc. (If I try creating a new folder, five new folders gets created in a second, but that's a problem for another day.)

However, this completely defies the whole point of a public share, since I have to enter valid credentials in Credential Manager to make it work. If the credentials aren't there, not only does the share not work, but Windows isn't even able to CONNECT to the server.

Anyone got any ideas? This is just one of several problems with file sharing in Windows 10, but maybe if I get this to work some other issues will be resolved in the process.

Since I love tormenting myself and wasting hours of my life, I uninstalled and purged Samba, rebooted (yeah, I know), and reinstalled it. Then I removed all shares from the default file and added only this:

```
[share_name]
    browseable = yes
    path = /home/public
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 777
```

Now, with or without the (unnecessary) credentials stored in Credential Manager, I am able to even access the Samba server, with the same error:

```
\\10.0.0.2 is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this      network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

A specified login session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

This is what file `log.smbd` says:

```
[2016/10/14 21:06:27.956914,  0] lib/util_sock.c:605(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): socket() call failed: Address family not supported by protocol
[2016/10/14 21:06:27.958765,  0] smbd/server.c:578(smbd_open_one_socket)
  smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address family not supported by protocol
[2016/10/14 21:06:27.997747,  0] printing/print_cups.c:110(cups_connect)
  Unable to connect to CUPS server localhost:631 - Connection refused
[2016/10/14 21:06:28.011317,  0] lib/util_sock.c:605(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): socket() call failed: Address family not supported by protocol
[2016/10/14 21:06:28.012127,  0] smbd/server.c:578(smbd_open_one_socket)
  smbd_open_once_socket: open_socket_in: Address family not supported by protocol
[2016/10/14 21:06:28.015107,  0]     printing/print_cups.c:487(cups_async_callback)
  failed to retrieve printer list: NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL
```

I know that Samba is used in lots of professional business organizations. How the heck do they get it to work? These errors are completely bogus and beyond all intelligence!

Comment: Could an admin please move this to Superuser? I posted it here by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 10 client needs some additional calls to be handled by the SMB server. I do not know if Samba supports them. A few other SMB servers does support Windows 10 and Windows 2016.